# How to make List height with same size?

Tags: java, android

list_match.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="85dp"
android:background="@drawable/list_selector"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
    android:background="@drawable/image_bg"
    android:padding="3dip" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/self_photo"
        android:layout_width="50dip"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:contentDescription="@string/desc" />
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/self_team"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:layout_below="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="12sp"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/opponent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/match_score"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/venue"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/self_team"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/date_time" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/player_status"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/team_name"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:textColor="#10bcc9"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:text="@string/opponent"
    android:textColor="@color/soft_grey"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/match_score"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/player_status"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/date_time"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/venue"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/opponent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/absent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/venue"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/venue"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/match_score" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/time_remain"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/opponent"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/opponent"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/opponent"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

is there a way change list like picture above with same height?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the TextView with id self_team with this parameters:

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/self_team"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/thumbnail"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignRight="@+id/thumbnail"
android:layout_below="@+id/thumbnail"
android:maxLines="1"
android:ellipsize="end"
android:gravity="center"
android:textSize="12sp"/>
```

so it will only have one line. Hope that helps.